# Plural of East European surnames

Tags: grammatical-number, names, surnames

Would the collective noun for the Ivanovic family be "Ivanoviches"?

> I called the Invanoviches for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

I think few would have a problem with that sentence if it were spoken aloud. But in writing, it's unlikely that the spelling "Ivanoviches" would be recommended by any mainstream source.

From Hellion's answer to a somewhat similar question ([plural of 'Davidovici'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11229/plural-of-davidovici)):

> The Chicago Manual of Style recommends that when a plural form suggests a false pronunciation, the name is best left unpluralized. (Preferably this would be done by recasting the sentence to avoid the need for pluralization.)

If you must pluralize a name that is spelled *Ivanovic* and pronounced with /tʃ/ (the *ch* sound of *rich*) as the last sound, the plural will presumably be regularly formed, and so pronounced with /tʃɨz/. As RegDwigнt♦ said in the comments, *-hes* is not a standard spelling of the regular English plural ending, so "Ivanoviches" is out.

#### I think it's unclear whether *Ivanovics* or *Ivanovices* would be the preferred spelling

The regular English plural ending is standardly spelled as either *-s* or *-es,* normally depending on the spelling and pronunciation of the word. For example, nouns ending in *ch* and pronounced with /k/ are spelled with *-chs* /ks/ (e.g. *[stomachs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/491380/77227)*), but nouns ending in *ch* and pronounced with /tʃ/ are spelled with *-ches* /tʃɨz/ (e.g. *beaches*).

But the usual alternation between *-s* and *-es* has at least one well-known exception for proper nouns: proper nouns ending in a consonant letter + *-y* often pluralize as *-ys,* even though common nouns ending in a consonant letter + *-y* regularly pluralize as *-ies.* The existence of that exception shows that we can't necessarily assume that the same rules apply to the spelling of plural common nouns and plural proper nouns. So even though the use of *-s* vs. *-es* is based on pronunciation for common nouns spelled with *-ch,* such as *stomachs* and *beaches,* the spelling pattern could be different for proper nouns ending in *-c.*

So I don't think there is any clear way to establish whether *Ivanovics* or *Ivanovices* is preferable. (However, the spelling *Ivanovic's* would presumably be rejected for containing a "greengrocer's apostrophe".)

#### Some actual examples of "Ivanovices"

I thought it might be useful to add some real examples of the spelling "Ivanovices" to this post to show that it is not just a theoretical invention. I admit that these examples are taken from sports writing, which is not known for perfect adherence to "standard" English:

- > Who will REALLY regard it as a big deal if **Ivanovic** or **Jankovic** does well in the Asian autumn swing? [...] Let’s acknowledge this about the **Ivanovices**, **Jankovices**, and Nishikoris of the world: They’re making a great living off tennis.

  ("[Seeds of Discontent and the Search for Identity in Tennis](http://thecomeback.com/attackingthenet/2015-articles/seeds-of-discontent-and-the-search-for-identity-in-tennis.html)", by Matt Zemek,  Aug 31, 2015 19:57, *Attacking the Net*)
- > instead of yet another list populated by the Sharapovas and the Wozniackis and the **Ivanovices**—some of the most googled female athletes in the world—I decided to a do a list of gorgeous tennis players at the Aussie Open that you’ve never even heard of.

  ("[15 Gorgeous Women You've Never Heard of at the 2012 Australian Open](https://www.totalprosports.com/2012/01/18/15-gorgeous-women-youve-never-heard-of-at-the-2012-australian-open/)", by Esteban, *TotalProSports.com*)
- > With all the Sharapovas and **Ivanovices** that are emerging in women's tennis, how many more big tournament wins are in the cards for the sisters?

  (transcript of Tony Cox in "[Shaquille Attacks Kobe with Raunchy Rap](https://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=91919447)", NPR *News & Notes*)

Answer (score -2):

Wiktionary does not provide a plural for the Serbo-Croatian surname *[Ivanovic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ivanovi%C4%87)*.

However,

> In January 1994, Igor and Ludmilla Ivanovic opened the doors of their bakery, … . The **Ivanovics** must decide how to reconfigure the leadership structure of the company without losing their control over the fundamentals. ([Gendron](https://hbr.org/product/iggys-bread-of-the-world/801282-PDF-ENG), Harvard Business Review) --emphasis mine.

And,

> The **Ivanovics** lived in a modest weatherboard home in Brunswick. (Shand, *Big Shots*, Accessed from [GoogleBooks](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=yJXbE-9iSTAC&pg=PT142&lpg=PT142&dq=%22the%20ivanovics%22%20-iggys%20-bread&source=bl&ots=cjgs_bB127&sig=vi4k_cUT1spDUHoHYWD1Kf0JBP4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOjPWCnN3bAhUSfH0KHc0QD-kQ6AEITDAK#v=snippet&q=ivanovics&f=false).) --emphasis mine.

To add to the woes, *Ivanovics* is also a surname.

OTOH,
**[Ivanoviches](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ivanoviches)** (Wiktionary)

> *plural* of **[Ivanovich](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ivanovich#English)**

[Ivanovich](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ivanovich#English) (plural Ivanovichs or Ivanoviches)

Comment: I guess the point is whether the **c** at the end is anglicized and pronounced as **k** (Ivanovic -> Ivinovics) or more authentically pronounced as **ch** (Ivanovic -> Ivanovices(?) Ivanoviches(?))

Comment: @GEdgar Some experienced *Ivanovic* could take offense at  "Ivanovices" though.

Comment: If *Ivanovic* is pronounced *Ivanovich*, then of course in English the plural is pronounced *Ivanoviches*, but how would you spell the plural?  I think it is a good question!

Comment: For what it's worth, in BHS the plural is *Ivanovići*. Also, while Bosnian, Croatian, and Serbian are considered dialects of the same language, calling the surname Serbo-Croatian might offend some people. I.e., just don't tell anyone from those areas that their surname is Serbo-Croatian (or refer to their dialect as such). The surname doesn't belong to a language either; it's merely written down in it. I mean whatever, but hopefully you'll get what I mean.

Comment: The plural in English is never formed using -hes. That is not a thing that English does. Ever. If we insist on the plural being Ivanoviches, we must insist on the singular being Ivanovich. If we insist on the singular being Ivanovic, then the plural is Ivanovics. Simple as that.

Comment: @GEdgar One advantage of using _Ivanovices_ rather than _Ivanovics_ is that it makes it clearer to those who do not know that the final 'c' in the singular is pronounced 'ch'. I'd always use the 'es' ending for names ending in a 'ch' sound but a simple 's' for ones ending in a hard 'c', I would read _Ivanovics_ as _Ivanoviks_.

Comment: Put at in and it works in English: “Ivanovitches”.

Comment: @David You obvious meant: "Put a ***t*** in and it works in English: “Ivanovitches”."

Comment: @Kris — Thanks,  I did. Can’t even write a single sentence properly on my phone. Not a very profound comment, but how I imagine an ordinary Brexit voter would handle it. (Of course I wouldn’t know.)