# The plural of 'stomach"

Tags: irregular-plurals

Words ending in ***ch*** usually take ***es*** in the plural form. However, the word  ***stomach*** is an exception to this paradigm. Its plural form is ***stomachs***. My question is, why does it take only ***s*** in the plural form?

Comment: Because English is a very weird and funny language, and never tends to follow the rules most of the times? Yup. :)

Comment: @BellaSwan Not really. Try to say "branchs" and you'll see why it's "branches"; try to pronounce "stomachs" and then wonder if "stomaches" would rhyme with "headaches".

Comment: The rule is not abut spelling but about sound.

Comment: Necessary [humorous] poem regarding sound in English [The Chaos](http://ncf.idallen.com/english.html).

Comment: Actually, the plural of "stomach" should have probably been "stomachia".

Comment: Plural of "stomach" is  "beergut" :-) .    @MikeNakis or "stomachata"

Comment: Yes, In English we consider the sound. Even in the use of a/an. For example ---->It is **An Honest man**. This is because of the sound

Comment: To reinforce @Ardent's point: different pronunciations change the rule since it's based on the sound: Americans observe a silent H in "herb" while the British pronounce it, so while Americans say "an herb", Brits say "a herb". This is also true for "a historic" (US) vs "an historic" (UK), but there's contention (historical baggage) with that example.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The use of the spelling "-ches" in plural forms of words that end in "-ch" is based on the presence of a vowel sound before the final /z/ sound. After the sound /t͡ʃ/, the plural suffix is pronounced as /ɪz/ (or /əz/ in some accents).

But *stomach* does not end in the sound /t͡ʃ/: it ends in the sound /k/, and the plural ends in /ks/, with no vowel sound sound before the final /s/. This is why it is not spelled with "-es".

Compare the two spellings of the plural of *[conch](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94255/the-plural-of-conch)* that correspond to the two pronunciation variants.

The regular plural suffix has the pronunciation /ɪz~əz/ and the spelling "-es" after any sibilant consonant sound: /s z ʃ ʒ t͡ʃ d͡ʒ/. Words ending in these sounds can be spelled in a variety of ways, so it's simpler to think of this rule as being based on pronunciation, not on spelling.

Comment: It is usually obvious if a word ends in a sibilant. ch is unusual in the large number of options, resulting from this digraph being used for a range of different purposes in different languages that we have borrowed, and using it in English in different ways for words of different origins. E.g. *sandwich* is of Norse origin, but *loch* and *quaich* are of Scots Gaelic origin. I once looked this rule up in the OED and it said it depended on if the ch was "soft" or "hard". Given the range of possibilities, I looked up these words, but, ironically, it did not define them in this sense!

Comment: I had seen *quaiches* and suspected it was wrong. I have just looked it up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaich) /ˈkweɪx/ and [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quaich) /-eɪx/ and I was very surprised as I have only ever heard /ˈkweɪç/. The extra confusion with the IPA here is that both x and ç are usually used for sibilant sounds, but in IPA they represent non-sibilants. For anyone not familiar with these sounds, /x/ is the ch in Gaelic/Scots loch or German Bach, and /ç/ is what you end up with if you try to pronounce this next to an e or i (quaich, dreich or German ich).

Answer (score 26):

If the -ch is pronounced like 'k', there is no 'e' before a plural final 's'. The lochs of Scotland are beautiful, also the mountains called the Trossachs. In music, there will be no more Bachs. Eunuchs cannot beget monarchs, and also cannot become patriarchs or, probably, the husbands of matriarchs.

Comment: We Richerbys aren't convinced that proper nouns are good examples of how plurals work in English. On the other hand, I suspect there won't be any more Shostakoviches, either, so maybe they aren't bad examples in this case.

Comment: Not only are all these examples proper nouns, they're also none of them English.  (Nor is Shostakovich for that matter).

Comment: Loch is not a proper noun, any more than 'lake', although individual lochs may use the word as part of their name, e.g Loch Ness, and the word is definitely English.

Comment: It's a borrowed word in English, but it comes from the Irish/Gaelic/Scots word for "lake".  Otherwise, what is the difference between a "loch" and a "lake"?  The only possible answer is whether it's in Scotland or not.

Comment: They have loughs in Ireland.

Comment: There are apparently close to [200,000 Bachs](https://forebears.io/surnames/bach) in the world today (most of them are Vietnamese). Who's to say that one of them won't become a great composer some day?

Comment: No-one is to say that, but they won't be the Johann Sebastian who composed _Matthäus-Passion_.

Comment: @ThePhoton That's a lot of Bachs!  Obviously not many were eunuchs.  Plenty of patriarchs and matriarchs though, I suppose.

Comment: There were 5 or 6 Bachs previously well known as composers.4 or 5 of them would probably be upset to hear we consider J. S. the only one worthy of consideration.

Comment: What about sassenach? I guess that reveals what TV show I've been watching....

Comment: I'm guessing it's either _Shetland_ or _Still Game_. I haven't seen the latest season of the latter yet.

Comment: I have seen Shetland, I LOVE it. :) I'm afraid it's Outlander....Have to look into Still Game. Thanks.

Comment: This answer gets to the point faster than the accepted answer and is more clear.

Comment: @WaterMolecule The accepted answer sure has a lot of typing in it.

Comment: No more Bachs and no more Rachs either.

Answer (score -1):

There are at least two reasons, one is the end sound 'k' in English words, but the other one is the plural of foreign words like stomach or Bach. The meaning of the name of the composers Bach (a family) is German for creek and the pronunciation of 'ch' is not 'k' at all but IPA 'x'. The English and German plural for the name 'Bach' is 'Bachs' (the plural of the word bach [= creek] is in fact Bäche 'ch' is IPA ç).